# How do I return '' for an empty node's text() in XPath?

Tags: xpath, libxml2

`<td></td><td>foo</td>`

I would like to return `['', 'foo']` but libxml's xpath `//td/text()` returns just `['foo']`. How do I find the empty tag as `''` instead of (not matched)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are selecting text nodes specifically, you can't. Because there simply is no text node in the first `<td>`.

When you change your XPath expression to `'//td'`, you get the two `<td>` nodes. Use their text value in further processing.

Comment: I wound up finding all the `td` nodes and calling .text on them. Not as cool as doing everything in one big XPath ;-) but it works.

Comment: @joeforker: As long as you don't have access to the all-shiny XPath 2.0, that's your only option. :-)

Answer (score 8):

While @Tomalak is perfectly right, **in XPath 2.0 one can use**:

`//td/string(.)`

and this produces a sequence of strings -- each one containing the string value of a corresponding `td` element.

So, in your case the result will be the desired one:

`"", "foo"`

Comment: +1. This does exactly what my solution does for XPath 1.0 - it takes the `<td>` nodes and then uses their respective text value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# pip install parsel
from parsel import Selector

html = """
<td>foo</td>
<td></td>
"""
selector = Selector(text=html)
tds = selector.xpath('//td').xpath('string(.)')

print([td.root for td in tds])
```

```bash
['foo', '']
```

similar if you use lxml.