# how to either return string or match empty if node/tag not found in xpath (lxml)

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following XPath to match authors name in an Amazon page:

> //div[@class='pTitle']/span[@class='small itemByline'] | //div[@class='pTitle']/span[not(text())]

The first part of this XPath matches it just fine, however some items in the page have no span after such div with class pTitle, so there's nothing to match, but I'd like to either get a '' or something else, to know the author was not found for real instead of just skipping it. I suppose the second XPath is invalid as it does not work...

For instance, the 3 titles starting with 'A Ditadura' should return '' for the author entry using the XPath I'm building. They're not though. It's making the above XPath return 179 items instead of 209.

Target is http://www.amazon.com/wishlist/3MCYFXCFDH4FA/ref=cm_wl_act_print_o?_encoding=UTF8&layout=standard-print&disableNav=1&visitor-view=1&items-per-page=1000

This is part of the code of my Python module https://github.com/caio1982/Amazon-Wishlist (thanks by the way for all the good answers in SO so far, I've learned XPath thanks to you guys).

For sake of info, I'm trying this using Firefox's XPath Checker extension, implementing it with Python (lxml).

It sounds similar to [How do I return '' for an empty node's text() in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420705/how-do-i-return-for-an-empty-nodes-text-in-xpath) but I'm not sure though.

I suspect the answer may be something around XPath axes and a [notcontains] restriction of some sort?

**EDIT1:** rephrasing it a bit after Dimitre's suggestion... is it possible to use –– and if so, do you have a working example of –– Becker's XPath method using lxml?

**EDIT2:** sample tree and expected results:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>First Paragraph</p>
            <p>Second paragraph: <span>value</span></p>
            <p>Third paragraph: <span>value</span></p>
            <p>Forth paragraph:</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

XPath //p/span returns the Second and the Third paragraph 'value' strings accordingly. That's ok, but I'm looking for 4 results instead of 2, like this:

```
    None
    value
    value
    None
```

I know //p/span does not work for this, hence I'm looking for some string-magic, node comparison or conditionals etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use an XPath expression like this one**:

```
concat(
//div[@class='pTitle']/span[@class='small itemByline'],
substring('UNKNOWN', 
          1 + 7*(boolean(//div[@class='pTitle']/span[@class='small itemByline'])
          )
       )
```

When this XPath expression is evaluated, and if `//div[@class='pTitle']/span[@class='small itemByline']` exists, then its string value (concatenated with the empty string) is produced.

When `//div[@class='pTitle']/span[@class='small itemByline']` doesn't exist, then the result is the string `'UNKNOWN'` -- the empty string is concatenated with `substring('UNKNOWN', 1+0`).

Here we use the fact that in XPath 1.0 whenever a boolean value is an argument of an arithmetic operator, it is first converted to a number, using the rule that:

```
   number(true()) = 1
```

and

```
   number(false()) = 0
```

**Update**: Here is an XSLT- based verification, using the XML document from the EDIT 2 by the OP and producing exactly the wanted result (the Same XPath expression (only an index is updated) is evaluated 4 times and all produced values are output -- each on a separate line):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[not(position() > count(//p))]">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat((//p)[position() = $vPos]/span,
             substring('UNKNOWN',
                       1 +7*boolean((//p)[position() = $vPos]/span)
                       )
             )
     "/>

     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the latest provided XML document**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>First Paragraph</p>
        <p>Second paragraph: 
            <span>value</span>
        </p>
        <p>Third paragraph: 
            <span>value</span>
        </p>
        <p>Forth paragraph:</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated N (4) times and the results of this evaluation are produced -- as we see, these are exactly the wanted results**:

```
UNKNOWN
value
value
UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dimitre, but I guess I'm missing something here. Your explanation makes sense, but I'm getting syntax error both in XPath Checker inside Firefox as well in Python's lxml. Is the substring correct or that 1+7* thing ok? I didn't quite understand the syntax, just the idea :-(

Comment: @caio1982: I don't know lxml. Usually there are two kind of functions that evaluate an XPath expression. One is to select nodes -- like `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()`. These function will raise an error if an XPath expression is passed as argument, that doesn't select a node. I think that this is what is happening in your case. On the other side, there are functions, that can evaluate *any* XPath expression -- not only expression that select nodes -- such as `Evaluate()`. You need to find such a function in lxml and use it.

Comment: Apparently this solution either return X or Y, not both (i.e. if a node is empty and the next one is not, return both but with different values, a real one and an 'exception' string). Or I must be doing it wrong...

Comment: @caio1982: I don't understand what you are saying in your last comment. Could you, please, rephrase?

Comment: Sorry. From what I understood and could test of it so far, it seems this approach will return either X or Y as a result, exclusively. Instead, I'm looking for a way to get both results: if the XPath matches then return its string or node or whatever, but if it does not match, also return something (an arbitrary string, say, 'blah'). So the XPath will always return the two values, not exclusively one of them (like the solution above does, apparently).

Comment: @caio1982: This doesn't make sense. You want: "Charles Dickens UNKNOWN" ??? Nobody does this. Please, edit the question and provide just a small XML document and also exactly what you want to obtain.

Comment: Done, please see EDIT2 above. I hope you don't go mad with it, it seems you're my best chance to get it right.

Comment: @caio1982: Yes, see the update to my question with verification that by evaluating 4 times the XPath expression (updating only a single index each time), the exactly wanted results are produced.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Dimitre. I've marked it as answered even though  using XSLT is far away from the point (XPath-only). I'll try a workaround in Python programmatically then.

Comment: @caio1982: I didn't mean at all that you have to use XSLT. You will evaluate the XPath expression in your environment (Python): `concat((//p)[position() = $vPos]/span,
             substring('UNKNOWN',
                       1 +7*boolean((//p)[position() = $vPos]/span)
                       )
             )`  -- where you will replace `$vPos` programmatically with the values 1, 2, ..., `count(//p)`