# Xpath - Return space for empty tags

Tags: xpath

For the following XML:

```
<Team>
        <Member>
            <ID>1234</ID>
            <Name/>
        </Member>
        <Member>
            <ID>5678</ID>
            <Name>Mark</Name>
        </Member>
</Team>"
```

I am trying to return a list of Names, with spaces as placeholders if they are blank.  Currently, I am using //Name/text().  This is returning only "Mark".  What I would like is an array {,Mark}.  What can I do to ensure that blank  tags are returned as spaces?

I apologize for any syntactical errors as I am very new to this.

Comment: you better tag you question better if you want it to get answers, what is the programming language and environment you are using etc, besides see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420705/how-do-i-return-for-an-empty-nodes-text-in-xpath

Comment: What host language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element `<Name/>` literally has no text child, so you'll probably want to select the target elements -- using `//Name` or something more specific -- and iterate over those in whatever language you're using to evaluate the XPath expression (replacing elements that have no text child with a single space).

Since you don't say what host language you're using, I cannot provide that portion of the code.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thanks.