# Is it possible for xpath to return NULL if there is no text data?

Tags: xpath

I am currently trying to extract all data from a table. Table data rows are formatted as `<td headers="h1" align="left"></td>` when there is no data.

Using the `etree.tostring()` method from the `lxml` library prints out these elements as `<td headers="h1" align="left"/>` instead of the source formatting.

Furthermore, using `xpath` if I run the code `tree.path('//td[@headers="h1"]/text()')` the resulting list does not include blank values where there is no data.

As I am trying to write these results to a CSV file, how do I include NULL, i.e. `""` when there is no data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would be to use `//td[@headers="h1"]` xpath to get the elements and then get the `.text` property on each:

```
from lxml import etree

data = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td headers="h1" align="left"></td>
        <td headers="h1" align="left">Text1</td>
        <td headers="h1" align="left"/>
        <td headers="h1" align="left">Text2</td>
        <td headers="h1" align="left"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(data)
print [element.text for element in tree.xpath('//td[@headers="h1"]')]
```

Prints:

```
[None, 'Text1', None, 'Text2', None]
```

If you want empty string instead of `None`:

```
print [element.text if element.text is not None else ''
       for element in tree.xpath('//td[@headers="h1"]')]
```

would print:

```
['', 'Text1', '', 'Text2', '']
```

Also see: [How do I return '' for an empty node's text() in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420705/how-do-i-return-for-an-empty-nodes-text-in-xpath)

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to do it using xpath, rather than python.

Comment: @Addikt no way, only in xpath 2.0.

Comment: Well, this will have to do then. Thanks.