# Xpath keep a place for empty node value

Tags: python, xpath

I try to extract values from this:

```
<tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td></td>
     <td>b</td> 
</tr>
```

//td/text() returns:

```
a
a
b
b
```

How can I get the following output?

```
a
a
b

b
```

Comment: Have you read this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420705/how-do-i-return-for-an-empty-nodes-text-in-xpath

Comment: The shared link is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `lxml.html` - loop over the `td` elements found and get the `text_content()`:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """
<tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td></td>
     <td>b</td>
</tr>"""

tree = fromstring(data)

for td in tree.xpath(".//td"):
    print(td.text_content())
```

Prints:

```
a
a
b

b
```