# Parsing XML document in PostgreSQL using XPATH?

Tags: xml, postgresql, xslt, xpath, xsd

Is there a way to parse the following XML document in PostgreSQL using XPATH to obtain desired output as

**--Corrected required output**

`promotion-id    price
new-promotion   null
new-promotion   null
new-promotion   300`

for the `price` element. Currently when I run the query provided below I get `300` as the output. My issue is my query ignores the price elements having `<price xsi:nil="true"/>` structure.

Is there a way to return `null` as result for the price elements with `<price xsi:nil="true"/>` type structure?

My code is something like:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT
'<promotions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <promotion promotion-id="old-promotion">
        <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>
        <searchable-flag>false</searchable-flag>
    </promotion>
    <promotion promotion-id="new-promotion">
        <enabled-flag>false</enabled-flag>
        <searchable-flag>false</searchable-flag>
        <exclusivity>no</exclusivity>
        <price xsi:nil="true"/>
        <price xsi:nil="true"/>
        <price>300</price>
    </promotion>
</promotions>'::xml AS t
)
SELECT unnest(xpath('//price/text()', node))::text 
FROM (SELECT unnest(xpath('/promotions/promotion', t)) AS node FROM x) sub
```

Any suggestions for the above issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no text to be extracted from the first two price elements.  [See discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420705/how-do-i-return-for-an-empty-nodes-text-in-xpath)  Postgresql is currently limited to [XPath 1.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) so we need to unnest the XML fragments and then convert them individually to text.

```
WITH x AS (SELECT
'<promotions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <promotion promotion-id="old-promotion">
        <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>
        <searchable-flag>false</searchable-flag>
    </promotion>
    <promotion promotion-id="new-promotion">
        <enabled-flag>false</enabled-flag>
        <searchable-flag>false</searchable-flag>
        <exclusivity>no</exclusivity>
        <price xsi:nil="true"/>
        <price xsi:nil="true"/>
        <price>300</price>
    </promotion>
</promotions>'::xml AS t
)
SELECT (xpath('@promotion-id',node))[1]::text AS "promotion-id", 
       (xpath('/price/text()',
              unnest(xpath('price',node))
       ))[1]::text AS price
  FROM (SELECT unnest(xpath('/promotions/promotion', t)) AS node FROM x) sub
```

Comment: thank you for the message. the proposed solution would have worked but the desired output requires reference to pormotion-id element. Please see the updated message. Appreciate your help.